# How do I open the default Ubuntu text editor from within a Tkinter program?

Tags: tkinter

My Tkinter program contains the following code:

```
def Run_Report():

    sPrinciple=e_SelectInv.get()

    Sql=("SELECT Principle as Investment, RptDate as Report_Date, printf('%,.2f',RptVal) as Report_Value, printf('%.2f',ExchRate) as Exchange_Rate, printf('%,d',RptVal*ExchRate) as Total_Value FROM MyInv WHERE Principle = ?" +
             "order by Id Asc")

    conn = sqlite3.connect(r'/home/bushbug/Databases/TrackMyInv')
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute(Sql,(sPrinciple,)) 
    col_names = [cn[0] for cn in curs.description]
    rows = curs.fetchall()
     
    x = PrettyTable(col_names)
    x.align[col_names[0]] = "l"
    x.align[col_names[1]] = "r"
    x.align[col_names[2]] = "r"
    x.align[col_names[3]] = "r"
    x.align[col_names[4]] = "r"
    x.padding_width = 1
    
    for row in rows:
        x.add_row(row)
     
    print (x)
    tabstring = x.get_string()
    output=open("export.txt","w")
    output.write("Population Data"+"n")
    output.write(tabstring)
    output.close()
     
    conn.close()
```

When I am using IDLE and run the program it opens the Shell Editor and produces a very nicely formatted report. However, I have created a desktop shortcut that launches the program. Then when I click "Run report" in the menu bar nothing happens as there is no text editor open. What must I include in the above to first open the default Ubuntu text editor?

Comment: Firstly, I need to clarify that I am using tkinter. Secondly, I have realised that I don't need the 4 lines starting with "output". I just need to know how to output the data to a text editor so that I can then send it all to a printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my Ubuntu 20.04.2, the default text editor can be run in the command line by entering `gedit`, and passing any files you want it to open as arguments. So by using the `os.system` command, which executes the string argument in the terminal, you can run the Ubuntu text editor in your program.

You must `import os` at the beginning of the program. I'm not sure where in your code you want to open the text editor, but this is what it would look like:

```
os.system("gedit")
```

or, if you want it to open a file:

```
os.system("gedit /path/to/your/file")
```

This, of course, will require you to write the data to a file in order to open it in another text editor, so it won't work for real-time updates to the output while the text editor is open.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. It is most informative and I will check it out. I must add that I have found PrettyTable very user friendly and am able to print out nicely formatted reports from it.